# Learning Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been working as WinForm (C#) Developer since Aug 2010. Now, I am planning to migrate into Asp.net MVC (C#). I have been learning MVC with http://www.asp.net/mvc for last 10 days. But I found that it only emphasizes on  razor technology over ASPX. I just want to clear doubt that Do you use Razor technology in your MVC Project over ASPX. Please also mention other stuff I should learn (or from where) to be an Asp.net MVC Developer (Good & Employed).

Thank you,
Aman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow (SO)

Razor is simply a template engine, meaning that you write a string and put placeholders in it to be filled by some data. Razor is really easy to use, thus:

```
hello @name
```

in Razor would be:

```
hello <%= name %>
```

in ASP default inline statements. Thus yeah, many developers recently prefer Razor.

If you want to become a good ASP.NET MVC developer, I suggest to follow these topics as starting point:

1. Filters
2. HTML Helpers
3. Razor Syntax
4. ViewBag, ViewData, and TempData
5. Routes

of course, these suggestions need you to know ASP.NET, and MVC, and many more stuff as prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

Using Razor is indeed a more effective approach then to use ASPX-page markup.

Razor is simpler and cleaner. With "cleanness" comes a better code-walk capabilities. In aspx we had a lot of syntactical junk on the way, and a developer's intention to alter or get to know the code were "wearing off" more quicky.

With Razor, you see a much broader picture of a page's view at a glance.

Razor is not the core of being a good ASP.NET developer though.

The following may be a **subjective optinon**, but as soon as you realize how web server (ports, urls, routing), Controllers, Views and JSON data fromat tick together, as soon as you are able to quickly parse server-generated JSON model on the client with KnockoutJS or other MVVM framework, making your pages go "alive", you are becoming a developer who can create a web site on his own. You should specialize in something, no doubt, but to be a good developer, you need fully understand how Microsoft Stack of web technologies ticks.

Comment: hmmm! That sounds quite great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Aman As far as Razor over ASPX concerns, I say yes Razor is widely used in industry and as you are beginner in ASP.NET MVC,  I suggest to learn MVC 4. You can get more info on MVC 4 from http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4 and here is article series covering new feature in MVC 4 http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2011/09/aspnet-mvc-4-article-series.html

Answer (score 0):

I have read 3 books on ASP.NET MVC and 2 books on the Entity Framework.    I have been developing in MVC 3 since it was released.  Absolutely the best resource I have found is Scott Allen's training courses on ASP.NET MVC 3 on http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/aspdotnet-mvc3-intro  Scott really knows his stuff.

This isnt just your typical canned developer training that is read from a script by a voice actor.  Scott really knows web development and he shares some great inside tips on programming MVC 3.  His C# stuff on http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/csharp-fundamentals is also very good.  No, I do not work for pluralsight, I am just a happy pluralsight.com subscriber.

You must know HTML, CSS, jQuery and JavaScript in order to be an effective and productive MVC 3 developer.   Go to http://www.w3schools.com/ and do all of the tutorials on those subjects.

Comment: Thank you. After getting basic training from www.asp.net/mvc. I was planning for pluralsight. Scott Allen is really great i also follow him on www.OdeToCode.com.